# VBA how do I loop through each table in an array

Tags: excel, vba

I want to clear and reset the conditional formatting on certain ListObjects in my work book. How do I create an array so that I can use for loops to apply the formatting. This was originally written to apply to the whole sheet, but now I want to restrict the routine to a table.

Here is my code:

```
Sub Reset()


'Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lo As Variant
Dim ArrTab As Variant
Dim ws As Variant
Dim Item As Variant
Dim ArrGreen As Variant

ArrTab = Array("Dept1710", "Dept1711", "Dept1713", "Dept1715", "Dept1716", "Dept1717")
ArrGreen = Worksheets("Drop down").Range("Q14:Q18").Value


For Each lo In ArrTab


lo.Select
Selection.FormatConditions.Delete

    For Each Item In ArrGreen
        Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlEqual, Formula1:=Item
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 5287936
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Next Item

Next lo

End Sub
```

ArrTab has all of the table names.

Answer (score 0):

If the tables resp. listobject all on the same worksheet the following fix could do it

```
Sub Reset()

    'Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lo As ListObject
    Dim ArrTab As Variant
    Dim ws As Variant
    Dim Item As Variant
    Dim ArrGreen As Variant

    ArrTab = Array("Dept1710", "Dept1711", "Dept1713", "Dept1715", "Dept1716", "Dept1717")
    ArrGreen = Worksheets("Drop down").Range("Q14:Q18").Value

    Dim sngElement As Variant                         ' Variable to loop throgh the array
    For Each sngElement In ArrTab

        Set lo = ActiveSheet.ListObjects(sngElement)  ' Assign the listobject
        ' lo.Range.Select                             ' uncomment if you need the complete listobject
        lo.DataBodyRange.Select                       ' select the data (without headers)
        Selection.FormatConditions.Delete

        For Each Item In ArrGreen
            Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlEqual, Formula1:=Item
            Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
            With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
                .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                .Color = 5287936
                .TintAndShade = 0
            End With
        Next Item

    Next sngElement

End Sub
```

But normally you do not need [Select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)